# How to improve this program's readability?

Tags: python, dictionary, readability

I'm learning the basic of Python dictionaries and am having an exercise on nesting dictionaries in a list. It basically told me to make 3 dictionaries about 3 people, nest them inside a list, loop through the list, and print out the info of each person.
I have already had the output I wanted, but my print statement was hard to read with a lot of \n. Can you suggest other ways to improve readability?

**My code:**

```
friend_1 = {
    "first_name": "Tu",
    "last_name": "Le",
    "age": 18,
    "city": "Hanoi"
}

friend_2 = {
    "first_name": "Hao",
    "last_name": "Do",
    "age": 18,
    "city": "Hanoi"
}

friend_3 = {
    "first_name": "Hieu",
    "last_name": "Tran",
    "age": 18,
    "city": "HCMC"
}

friends = [friend_1, friend_2, friend_3]

for friend in friends:
    print(f"\nFirst name: {friend['first_name'].title()}\nLast name: {friend['last_name'].title()}\nAge: {friend['age']}\nCity: {friend['city'].title()}")
```

The output looks somewhat like this:

```
First name: Tu
Last name: Le
Age: 18
City: Hanoi
```

Comment: You could split them into separate print statements. E.g. `print("first\nsecond")` is the same thing as `print("first")` with `print("second")` on the next line.

Comment: Please don't use screen grabs for purely textual information. Copy/paste the text into the question.

Comment: I understand, @KurtisRader. I did paste the text but they just appeared in 1 line instead of multiple lines like the actual output.

Comment: @HazelP, Put a line of three backquotes above and below the literal text -- just like you would for a code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the problem is the way it appears in the print statement, you can make use of the fact print can take in lots of arguments to print and then specify a `sep`arator that can be used to define how to separate all the individual elements you've included in the print statement

```
print(
     f"First name: {friend['first_name'].title()}",
     f"Last name: {friend['last_name'].title()}",
     f"Age: {friend['age']}",
     f"City: {friend['city'].title()}",
     sep="\n"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you got the expected answer, but I still want to give you a small example of how you can control the way to print your data structure, and how to avoid using a certain character repeatly.

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, first_name: str, last_name: str, age: int, city: str):
        self.dict = {"first_name": first_name, 
                     "last_name": last_name, 
                     "age": age, 
                     "city": city}
        
    def __str__(self):
        s = "\n".join([f'Fist name: {self.dict["first_name"].title()}',
                       f'Last name: {self.dict["last_name"].title()}',
                       f'Age: {self.dict["age"]}',
                       f'City: {self.dict["city"]}'])
        return s

friend_1 = Person("Hieu", "Tran", 18, "HCMC")

print(friend_1)
```